# Using scanf to scan multiple chars and ints at once

Tags: c, scanf

Question seems relatively straight-forward and basic. Seems like it would have been asked before, but I couldn't find anything using search engines. Pretty much I need a user to input multiple variables and i  store then in one scan. I'm new to C so I wasn't sure why this wasn't working. I know it's something novice, but being a novice at C I'm not sure.

Pretty much the user would input something like "* 2 4", but for some reason the variables values never get changed in the next method.

Even if I put `printf("Values are %d and %d", &start, &end);` immediately after the scan, the values still don't change.

```
char symb;
int start, end;
printf("Enter a symbol, a start point, and an end point : ");
scanf("%c %d %d", &symb, &start, &end);
do_function(symb, start, end);
```

Comment: what is `symb` here?. provide  do_function() body

Comment: "I couldn't find anything using search engines" -- then read the man page (or some other documentation) of the function you want to use.

Comment: oh sorry that was just a copy error. I fixed it. And the do_function just prints out the values of the symb, start and end. But the values never get changed from the scan funtion

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `scanf()` succeeded by inspecting its return value; if it doesn't return `3`, your code won't be able to continue since the values were not scanned.

Comment: in my do_function method, it prints out the values of the variables passed, and they are never changed from the scan function, so that's why I was asking here what I was doing incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Add space before `"%c"` to consume preceding white-space and check `scanf()` results.

```
if (scanf(" %c %d %d", &symb, &start, &end) != 3) {
  puts("Bad input");
  exit (-1);
}
```

`scanf("%c %d %d", &symb, &start, &end)` consumes *any* `char` and saves it into `symb`.  Often this is the `'\n'` from the previous line.  Then the attempt to read a number is stopped by `'*'`.

A better approach is to read the entire line, and then scan it.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOErrorOrEOF();
if (sscanf(buf, " %c %d %d", &symb, &start, &end) != 3) {
  puts("Bad input");
  exit (-1);
}
do_function(symb, start, end);
```

Note: `" %c %d %d"` could be `" %c%d%d"` as all specifiers except `"%c"`, `"%n"` and `"%["` consume leading white-space even without a leading `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

figured out it was wrong with my print methods (was using the ampersand when it's not needed)